# Reading Website That Has Japanese

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii, urllib

`UnicodeDecodeCharacter 'ascii' cocec can't decode byte 0xe3 at position 348: ordinal not in range(128)`

I have `urllib.urlopen`-ing a website, and I have a `.readlines()` going through it paragraph by paragraph, searching for certain text.

I reading from a website that has a few Japanese characters on it (I WANT TO SKIP THIS PART), but my code crashes when it reads over it.

Or on a simpler note, can I convert the entire `urllib.urlopen` to a unicode so that I don't get this ASCII error, and if so, how do I search through it?

Comment: Please tell us what *language* you're talking about, show us some actual code and maybe even show us the website you're talking about.

Comment: @Iria Zeiram: The URL, and code, please.

Comment: @deceze: This appear to be Python, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: @Thanatos It possibly is, but who can say for sure?

Comment: @deceze: The error message matches that of a Python exception, and it mentions `urllib.urlopen` and a `readlines` method. Know any other languages that have those?

Comment: We're not psychic. Show the actual code so we can figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can read in the raw bytes, convert them to ascii (while ignoring non-ascii) and then split the lines:

```
import urllib

url = 'http://www.asahi.com/'
u = urllib.urlopen(url)
rawdata = u.read()
u.close()
asciidata = rawdata.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
asciilines = asciidata.splitlines(False)

for line in asciilines[:40]:
    print line
```

This code should be you started.  The more technically correct way involves reading the headers or the first few lines of the body to find the correct charset and then decoding using that charset.